# Understanding underscore's implementation of isNaN

Tags: javascript, numbers, underscore.js, nan

Taken from the underscore.js source:

```
_.isNaN = function(obj) {
  return _.isNumber(obj) && obj != +obj;
};
```

Why did they do it this way? Is the above implementation equivalent to:

```
_.isNaN = function(obj) {
  return obj !== obj;
};
```

If it is, why the "more complicated" version? If it is not, what are the behavioural differences?

Comment: Or even simpler, the native `isNaN` function...

Comment: @Kolink taken from the Underscore docs: "Note: this is not the same as the native isNaN function, which will also return true if the variable is undefined"

Comment: @Kolink `isNaN(undefined)` gives true.

Comment: Just like `isNaN("NaN")`...

Comment: Is the purpose of the "is not a number" function not to find out if a variable is not a number?

Comment: The new-ish `Number.isNaN()` is different from the old `isNaN()` in that it insists that its argument must be a number (lower-case) in order to be `NaN`, and it will specifically return `false` when passed `new Number(NaN)` as an argument.

Comment: @Kolink `isNaN` is meant to detect the `NaN` object (like `isNaN(0/0)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_.isNaN(new Number(NaN))` returns true.

And that's [by design](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/issues/749).

```
var n = new Number(NaN);
console.log(_.isNaN(n), n!==n); // logs true, false
```

Comment: So will `Number.isNaN()` nowadays.

Comment: @Pointy `Number.isNaN(new Number(NaN))` returns `false` as of Chrome 26.0.1410.65 and FireFox 21

Comment: @Andbdrew yes that's what I meant - `Number.isNaN()` returns true only when its argument is of primitive type 'number' (not 'Number'), and is the special 'NaN' constant.

Answer (score 1):

The host environment (e.g. web-browser environment) may introduce other values that aren't equal to themselves. The `_.isNumber(obj)` part makes sure that the input is a Number value, so that `_.isNaN` only returns `true` if the `NaN` value is passed.

Comment: Do you have an example of a host environment that introduces a value that isn't equal to itself?

Comment: @Randomblue Nope. I have never heard of such a value, hence the *may*.

Comment: Ok. Clever thinking though, that in theory the host environment puts all bets off.

Answer (score 0):

If + is given before of any value with no preceding value to + , JavaScript engine will try to convert that variable to Number.If it is valid it will give you the Number else it will return NaN.  For example

```
 + "1" // is equal to integer value 1
 + "a1" // will be NaN because "a1" is not a valid number
```

In above case

```
 +"a1" != "a1" // true, so this is not a number, one case is satisfied
 +"1" == "1" // true, so it is number
```

Another simple case would be, why the below expression give this output

```
 console.log("Why I am " + typeof + "");
 // returns "Why I am number"
```

Because +"" is 0.

If you want to check whether it is a number or not you could use the below function

```
function isNumber(a){ 
   /* first method : */  return (+a == a);
   /* second method : */  return (+(+a) >= 0);
   // And so many other exists
}
```

Someone correct me if I am wrong somewhere..

Comment: There are no integers in JavaScript. `+"1.5e-1"`

Comment: @Bergi Does the above function fail with +"1.5e-1" ?. And yes, Integer instead of Number is Typo.. I agree.. What do you call 0.1 in javaScript..?

Comment: No, but `0.15` is an example for a non-integer, plain *number* :-)

Comment: @Bergi Please look into my updated answer. Does it deserve down vite :-). I dont think any of the above explanation is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found one case for _.isNaN
It shows different result with the native one if you pass there an object

```
_.isNaN({}) => false
//but
isNaN({}) => true
```